The certificate for this server is invalid. Error for rendering image in react native
I built a react native app using expo developer.
I added to my app.json under iOS this attributes:
"NSAppTransportSecurity": {
          "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads":true,
          "NSExceptionDomains": {
              "localhost": {
                  "NSIncludesSubdomains": true,
                  "NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads": true,
                  "NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy": true,
                  "NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads":true,
                  "NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads": true,
                  "NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy": true,
                  "NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion":"TLSv1.1",
                  "NSRequiresCertificateTransparency": false
              }
          }
      }

and trying to render this image:
             <Image
  source={{uri:"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocKxV5jCaivU82tHuNRqAyt8jasfBXwBtmWz_3YQBEZplg=s120"}}
  style={styles.avatar}
  onError={(error) => console.log(error.nativeEvent.error)}
/>

and getting this error:
The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “lh3.googleusercontent.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.

How can I solve this issue?

The certificate presented by the server when manually accessing the URL in question is indeed valid; are you testing this behind some sort of SSL terminating firewall, proxy or other intermediary which might bork the certificate's validation? Is the time on the device being used to conduct the testing set correctly?

I am using expo simulator for testing.

Sorry, but that doesn’t really answer the question. Is the device on which the simulator is running behind some sort of firewall or other network appliance that is MiTMing your connection between your device and Google’s servers to the point where the certificate that’s presented is not valid?

This is my work computer, which belongs to my company. I suspect that a particular configuration may be causing the issues I am encountering. How can I verify this? I can see the image when I access it via Safari from my Mac, if that's of any help.

When you have the URL in question opened in Safari, click the padlock in the address bar to view the certificate that's in use to secure your traffic. If the certificate chain contains any information that doesn't belong to Google's Trust Services subsidiary, it's likely your employer has configured your machine to trust one of said appliances in a way that the iOS simulator has not. (1/2)

Once you have a view on which certificate in your keychain specifically is being used as the root CA upon inspection in Safari, you can locate & install that certificate file and trust it in the simulator. (2/2)

I'm seriously appreciative of your help. It's working. Thank you!
